# Android Studio - What method is used to detect exiting app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project with an edittext. I want to save the content in the edittext upon exiting the app (without a button). How can I detect when a user exits app, so I can save then?

Comment: overide activity onStop or onDestroy method and save value.
How you are storing value?

Comment: Can you show me  a short code example? I'm new to android studio and this whole concept of app development. I would love if you could attach a short code showing what you mean :)

Comment: Can you post your activity class? so that I can modify it for you

Comment: you can detect through back button press onBackPressed() function. or you can use textwatcher on edittext when user ends typing then save text.

Answer (score 0):

use autoCompleteTextView and add textWatcher, on completed editing, save value in sharedprefrences

```
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextViewActivation;
    autoCompleteTextViewActivation = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text_view_activation);

    autoCompleteTextViewActivation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //TODO: save in sharedPrefrences
        }
    });
```

and in on create or on resume... check if you has value in sharedPrefrences set it to autoCompletedTextView